# Appending text to user's account after IdP authentication / before SP redirect

Tags: php, authentication, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

I need to append the email domain (@domain.com) to a user's account after they are IdP validated, and before the system redirects them to the SP.

I am using this page for assistance but am unable to assert whether I will type in the additional text literally, or by referencing another attribute retrieved from LDAP: http://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-authproc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must apply the filter at the metadata/saml20-idp-hosted.php

Use a [PHP filter](http://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/core%3aauthproc_php):

```
'authproc.idp' => array(
    60 => array(
        'class' => 'core:PHP',
        'code' => '
             if (!empty($attributes["uid"])) {
                  $mail = $attributes["uid"][0] . "@domain.com";
                  $attributes["mail"] = array($mail);
             } //Closing bracket was missing
        ',
    ),
 ),
```

This filter for example create a 'mail' attribute based on an 'uid' attribute.
Note that attribute values at the $attributes are always an array.

Comment: Yes, if you put this on config.php the filter will be applied for the  IdP defined on metadata/saml20-idp-hosted.php and in all the SP defined on the config/authsources.php

Reference: http://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-authproc?#section_1