# python-saml (OneLogin) equivalent to SimpleSAMLphp filters

Tags: python, django, saml, saml-2.0, onelogin

I'm wondering whether [python-saml library from OneLogin](https://github.com/onelogin/python-saml) (we use it as an SP) has features semantically similar to [processing filters](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-authproc) in SimpleSAMLphp (our IdP), as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043820/appending-text-to-users-account-after-idp-authentication-before-sp-redirect) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50260272/how-to-replace-a-value-of-nameid-with-attribute-in-simplesamlphp-based-idp/50274721#50274721), for example.

The use case for us would be: in an IdP-initiated flow from the different clients, what if the attribute names differ from client to client and our logic depends on certain names of those attributes.  For example, client sends in a group name (or role) based on which entitlement decision in our SP are made.  Or something similar, i.e. a client has an attribute capitalized which is not the case in our environment.

What would be a proper `python-saml` feature to utilize for remapping of the incoming attributes on a consistent basis.  Or should we develop it ourselves to keep the mappings of idiosyncrasies of each client onto our conceptual model?  And in the latter case, are there any hooks in the `python-saml` library that we could utilize (we are Django specific).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Pysaml2](https://github.com/IdentityPython/pysaml2) supports this through the `attribute_map_dir` setting. OneLogin's python saml code does not.